# Comparing tuples to a list of non-tuples

Tags: python, tuples

Wrote the code below to take in a list/set and a string and if I am able to break the string into two words that are in the list then I return. I know I'm close, I just cant get the comparison right or something.

e.g.

```
wordBreakEasy("snowfall", ("apple", "fall", ..., "snow"))
```

would return `True`.

```
def wordBreakEasy(str1, wordset):
   wordset1 = set(wordset)
   breakup = ['%s %s' % (str1[:i], str1[i:]) for i in range(1, len(str1))]
   newlist = []
   for x in breakup:
     newlist.append((x.split()))
   wordset2 = set(map(tuple, newlist))

   for wordset2 in wordset1:
```

This is where I don't know where to go now.

Comment: Just to doublecheck; `"snowflake"` would not return True because `'flake'` is not in the word set, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your word pairs as tuples, rather than as a space-delimited single string, then filter that list on tuples that are a *subset* of your `wordset1` set:

```
breakup = [(str1[:i], str1[i:]) for i in range(1, len(str1))]
present = [tup for tup in breakup if not wordset1.issuperset(tup)]
```

I used the [`set.issuperset()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.isdisjoint) here; it returns `True` if all of the elements in the argument iterable are present in the set, so if it returns `True` only if both elements in the tuple are present.

Only *then* combine the words into a single string:

```
newlist = [' '.join(tup) for tup in present]
```

You don't need those intermediary lists, really; you only need to find if there is *any* such tuple that is a subset for your function to return `True`:

```
breakup = ((str1[:i], str1[i:]) for i in range(1, len(str1)))
return any(wordset1.issuperset(tup) for tup in breakup)
```

I turned `breakup` into a generator expression; no need for the whole list to be built if you can find a matching word-pair early on. The [`any()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) returns `True` as soon as one of the values it iterates over is true. Since that's a generator expression too, this tests word pairs lazily until a match is found.

Demo:

```
>>> def wordBreakEasy(str1, wordset):
...     wordset1 = set(wordset)
...     breakup = ((str1[:i], str1[i:]) for i in range(1, len(str1)))
...     return any(wordset1.issuperset(tup) for tup in breakup)
...
>>> wordBreakEasy("snowfall", ("apple", "fall", "...", "snow"))
True
>>> wordBreakEasy("snowflake", ("apple", "fall", "...", "snow"))
False
```

Comment: Is yours actually printing True or False?? My just ends finishes with exit code 0. I know, dumb question. Just trying to rap my head around it all. Actually just read through your most recent edit. All clear now! This needs 17 thumbs up. thx

Comment: @KelvinDavis: the function *returns* a boolean value. If you were supposed to print that value, add `print()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with itertools.combinations

```
def word_break(s, words):
    return (s in map("".join, itertools.combinations(words , 2)) or
            s in map("".join, itertools.combinations(words[::-1] , 2)))

word_break('snowfall', ['fall', 'green', 'white', 'cheese', 'snow'])
```

> True

Comment: Try that algorithm with 1000 words in `words`. :)

Comment: :) indeed, but it is still a nice solution when len(words) < 3000